# Logo license remove

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, photo-editing, copyright, image-editing

I have downloaded small image that I want to use it on my website but I have to buy it and really I couldn't do that. Also I want to do some changes in it.

The question: If I downloaded the image and made some changes with Photoshop, do I still need to follow the license or buy the image?

I mean I already changed it so it's not the same image that they have.

Comment: I am wondering why this question got downvoted, it's a really bad idea but it's definitely useful material for people who consult this site.

Comment: I like to refer to this blogpost: http://waxy.org/2011/06/kind_of_screwed/

Comment: Legally? Yes. Ethically? Yes. Will you get in trouble if you don't? Maybe, maybe not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question contains a very delicate topic: plagiarism...! As you guess, that's not very ethical and safe to copy images online and modify them, to then use them for commercial projects. Especially if you are totally aware of what you're doing and know a license is easily available.

"Making changes" is quite a relative term. It would be hard to judge what you did exactly and if you made enough changes to make the original image unrecognizable just by using the details from your question.

Finally, we can't really give you precise advice unless we can at least see the before and after of the image you're talking about; plus it's legal advice that fall in a gray zone where there's no precise guidelines (eg. infringement). What can be done is at least tell you objectively if your logo looks plagiarized or not.

---

**Some big clues to help you:**

- If you put the original and modified versions next to each others, is
  it easy for anyone to see the second image is built using the first
  one? If yes, buy the license.
- Also, if you remove what you copied from the original image and
  replace it by another custom design you did, will that logo still
  work or do you absolutely need to use the original image to achieve a similar result? If it doesn't work, buy the license. If you can use any other graphic to replace the copied image then **maybe** you'll be fine.  Note that I put the "maybe" in bold since you could still receive a cease and desist letter and there could still be infringement!

There's unfortunately no magical formula to this.

**Finally, even if you do buy the license, make sure to read the terms.**

Some licenses are not meant to be used on commercial projects as you want to use it for. In general, it's wiser and safer to build a logo from scratch and do some research to avoid any issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it be just easier to say no you cant do this. In theory and practice you can bet away with it. But it is still derivative work and you know it. Simply put starting form scrtach is much harder than starting from a template and copyright demands you to start form scratch even if you implement the same idea. Simply put its their image if you didn't start form a blank canvas according to copyright. And its still plagiarizing even if you did.

Comment: @joojaa That's what first and last sentences of my answer say :) And in-between are the kind of thing a judge would look at to decide if there's infringement or not. As for using "template", the twitter logo is a good example of a clipart used as logo and everything was done in a legal way. There's also banks of logos sold online, but we don't know exactly if this is a logo from that kind of bank here.

Comment: Yes but the message gets lost in the maybe between. For OP rest assured that you will know doing wrong for original author.

Comment: I totally got your answer and im really thankful but i want to ask if i could make a similar one with few differences would it be legal ?

Comment: @chipbuddy Not really, especially if you are aware you're copying someone's else work!

Comment: i am gonna make it from scratch i wont copy a single pixel but i mean im gonna do something the same in the idea

Comment: @chipbuddy Only you knows how close to the original your idea will be! But for example... that'd be a bit playing with fire to draw a big yellow M using the Futura font and the same effects as the Mcdonald curvy yellow M!

Comment: please take a look at this "http://www.flaticon.com/packs/pets-icons" i want to use some of these icons in my website and they are free but have some license .. I can recreate them from scratch with some differences like in the cat and dog icon

Comment: It sounds as though you are looking for some supposed authority to give you permission. I don't think go-junta (or anyone really) can be that authority except the copyright holder. Beyond that you are on your own

Comment: guys im not a bad guy who want to steal something and asking for permission! I asked this question to not do something illegal or take someone else work. I just loved the cat idea and I want to create it my own

Comment: @chipbuddy I love cats too! You can create a cat, cats are not a copyrighted idea :D Just not the same exact cat with the same distinctive features besides a tail and whiskers and pointy ears! And Yorik is right, not trying to patronize or judge you, don't worry.

Comment: okay
thanks a lot guys you really helped me :D

Comment: @chipbuddy in most cases you can copy a style or aesthetic.

Comment: @chipbuddy: Why don't you take a photo of a cat, dog etc. then roughly trace its outline?  Style is everything, though, and perhaps developing your own style would give extra life to your website. Do something innovative instead of plagiaristic.